# Why my modal bottom sheets don't show Drag handle?

Tags: material-ui, material-components-android, android-bottomsheetdialog

For some reason, the Drag handle is not visible on my modal bottom sheets.

My main theme is a descendant of the `Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar`.

The bottom sheet style is added to the theme:

```
<item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/SnThemeOverlay.BottomSheet</item>
```

The bottom sheet theme:

```
<style name="SnBottomSheet" parent="Widget.Material3.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize</item>
    <item name="behavior_skipCollapsed">true</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">?attr/colorSurfaceContainerLowest</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">?attr/colorSurfaceContainerLowest</item>
    <item name="bottomSheetDragHandleStyle">@style/Widget.Material3.BottomSheet.DragHandle</item>
</style>

<style name="SnThemeOverlay.BottomSheet" parent="ThemeOverlay.Material3.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/SnBottomSheet</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/SnButton.Big.Accent</item>
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/SnButton.Big.Accent</item>
</style>
```

As you can see I am even directly setting the default DragHandle style.

I have checked the official documentation on [bottom sheets](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/BottomSheet.md) and discussed this question with Bard and ChatGPT. But the given answers did not help me at all.

Any ideas?